# getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND while connecting to SQL Server from Node.js

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am trying to connect to my SQL Server from Node.js and I am getting this exception:

> ERROR: Failed to connect to WAMG9120116\SQLEXPRESS:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND WAMG9120116\SQLEXPRESS.

Below is the configuration.

```
# DATABASE
DATABASE_NAME=AeroPresentationApi
DATABASE_HOST=WAMG9120116\SQLEXPRESS
DATABASE_PORT=1433
DATABASE_USERNAME=XXXX
DATABASE_PASSWORD=XXXXXX
RUN_MIGRATIONS_ON_STARTUP=true
```

We are connecting to DB via this:-

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  databaseConfig.database,
  databaseConfig.username,
  databaseConfig.password,
  databaseConfig,
);
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on ?

NOTE: I was able to connect to SQL Server from SSMS using User Name and Password.

Comment: which node js sql module you are using?

Comment: @metal - Sequelize

Comment: sorry, i cant help coz i'm using msnodesqlv8 which supports both sql and windows authentication